Why is occurrence of ** for headings in GPT 4o responses not getting suppressed?
I am getting response for queries using API that might have headings in answers for GPT 4o. Like below:
**Heading**:\n - Details on the heading…
But I do not want these headings within asterisks or any other formatting.
Adding prompt for the same, code changes - Neither is working. The asterisk formatting is not getting removed.
Is it not possible to remove these asterisks in GPT 4o? If yes kindly suggest the solution.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried lots of prompts like -

Please ensure that all headers are formatted without any asterisks. Use simple, plain text for headers. For example Do not give Heading: , Heading- , etc as header, instead give Heading: , Heading- , etc in response.
Please generate a response using plain text only. Do not use any special characters such as asterisks, underscores, or any other symbols for headers, emphasis or formatting. Ensure all text is in standard, unformatted form.
Do not provide *text1*, **text2** i.e. words within special symbols in response. Always provide response as text1, text2 without any special symbols and in plain text format only.

And many other prompts. None of the prompts are able to suppress these asterisk
Also tried suppressing it in code using logit_bias
logit_bias = {
334: -100, # “**”
3146: -100, # " **"
}

Neither is working.

answer.replace("**", ""); is what you are looking for.
Alternatively, load a markdown library (in whatever language you are using) and use it to remove markdown.
